# How to save and display dynamic added data to json using php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I have a simple block in which a user can add multiple buttons on click, now I am using push to add those buttons to json, now I want to use PHP to save the added buttons to a json file.

**UPDATE as per Arleigh Hix**

My json looks like this

```
    var movies = [{
      "title": "travel",
      "left": 201,
      "top": 209,
      "movieid": "10",
      "movie_url": "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4",
      "buttons": [{
        "left": 81,
        "top": 51,
        "start_time": 1,
        "end_time": 2,
        "buttonid": "10_1",
        "btn_url": "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4"
      }]
    },
    {
      "title": "ecommerce",
      "movieid": "20",
      "movie_url": "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4",
      "buttons": [{
        "left": 0,
        "top": 0,
        "start_time": 1,
        "end_time": 2,
        "width": '200',
        "height": '60',
        "buttonid": "20_1",
      }]
    }
  ]
```

Here is HTML block for adding buttons

```
 <div id="layers-container" style="width: 375px;">
      <div class="layer"></div>
 </div>
```

Here is js

```
      $("#add-button").on("click", function(index){

                        var layer = $("<div class='layer'><div class='content-layer'></div></div");

                        $("#layers-container").append(layer);
                        var clickarea = $("<div class='clickarea'></div>");
                        $(".caption-content").append(clickarea);                       
                        $('.content-layer').each(function(index){
                                var value = index + 1;     
                                $(this).attr('id','contentLayerID' + value);
                        });

                        $('.clickarea').each(function(index){
                                var value = index + 1;    
                                $(this).attr('id','clikckAreaID' + value);
                                for (var a = 0; a < movies.length; a++) {
                                        for (var j = 0; j <movies[a].buttons.length; j++) {
                                                movies[j].buttons.push({
                                                        left: 20,
                                                        top: 20,
                                                        buttonid:clickarea.attr('id', 'clickAreaID', value)
                                                });

                                  };

                                }

                                    $.post('save_to_json.php', {movies:movies}, function(data, textStatus){
                                        console.log(textStatus, data);
                                    });
                        });

   })
```

Here is php file i started: save_to_json.php

```
   <?php
if(isset($_POST['movies'])){
    $movies = json_decode($_POST['movies']);
    // do whatever checks you need on $movies to verify valid data

    $success = file_put_contents("data.json", json_encode($movies));
    if($success === false){
        echo "Failed to write data to file";
        die();
    }else{
        echo "$success bytes were written to the file";
        die();
    }
}

$data=file_get_contents("data.json");
$result=json_decode($data);
?>
```

I am getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
>       at e (jquery.min.js:4)
>       at Vc (jquery.min.js:4)

To be honest, am new to PHP, I don't know what to do next.

What do I need to do to get what I want?

Comment: You are missing a space between < and movies `for (var j = 0; j <movies[a].buttons.length; j++) {`

Answer (score 1):

After your `.each()` function, send the updated json to the php file: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
$("#add-button").on("click", function(index){
    ...

        $('.clickarea').each(function (index) {
            ...        
        });

        let jsonString = JSON.stringify({movies:movies});
        $.post('myPhpFileURL', jsonString, function(data, textStatus){
            console.log(textStatus, data);
        });

    });
```

In the php file check for and retrieve data from $_POST https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php,

Then save the data https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['movies'])){
    $movies = json_decode($_POST['movies']);
    // do whatever checks you need on $movies to verify valid data

    $success = file_put_contents("file.json", json_encode($movies));
    if($success === false){
        echo "Failed to write data to file";
        die();
    }else{
        echo "$success bytes were written to the file";
        die();
    }
}

$data=file_get_contents("file.json");
$result=json_decode($data);
?>
```

Comment: I have updated my question added more code, can you check if am doing the right way I have minor problems now

Comment: By using your suggestion I am getting this error : `jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Comment: Sorry, I may have sytax errors (untested code) but this is the basic flow. Read the docs and apply the principles to your code.

Comment: am checking now , I have update as per your suggestion check it if its the right way I have Implemented

Comment: Unfortunatelly I am getting the error , i tried different combination as per stack overflow but nothing is working :(

Comment: it may need to be JSON.stringify({'movies':movies}) (quoted key)

Comment: solved the problem, and I am getting the success message but when I check data.json still have old data , I am missing something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195481/discussion-between-user9964622-and-arleigh-hix).

Answer (score 0):

Please describe a bit more in detail what you are trying to do, so the community can be of better help to you.

To write the JSON string to a file in PHP you can simply do:

```
<?php
file_put_contents("file.json", $_POST['movies']);
```

Assuming that you first JSON encode your array in Javascript and then POST the JSON string to the PHP script with an HTML form.